# Entity Framework Core incorrect field size

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm working on a dotnet core 2.1 application with entity framework core and SQL Server 2017 Express Edition. I created the migration and did the update and everything went smoothly, however, when querying the database I noticed that the size of the fields was not applied according to the migrations.

How can I fix this in my migration?

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Fornecedor",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            IdSistemaAntigo = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 32, nullable: false),
            Status = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            DataCadastro = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            UltimaMovimentacao = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            TipoPessoa = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            Nome = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
            Apelido = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 100, nullable: true),
            Sexo = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
            Cnpj = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 14, nullable: false),
            InscricaoEstadual = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 15, nullable: false),
            EstadoEmissorInscricaoEstadual = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 2, nullable: false),
            InscricaoMunicipal = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 20, nullable: false),
            Cpf = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 11, nullable: false),
            Rg = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 15, nullable: false),
            EstadoEmissorRg = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 2, nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Fornecedor", x => x.Id);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "FornecedorEmail",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            IdSistemaAntigo = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 32, nullable: false),
            Status = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            DataCadastro = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            UltimaMovimentacao = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            FornecedorId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            EnderecoEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 254, nullable: false),
            NomeExibicao = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 40, nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_FornecedorEmail", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_FornecedorEmail_Fornecedor_FornecedorId",
                column: x => x.FornecedorId,
                principalTable: "Fornecedor",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "FornecedorEndereco",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            IdSistemaAntigo = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 32, nullable: false),
            Status = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            DataCadastro = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            UltimaMovimentacao = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            TipoLogradouro = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 72, nullable: false),
            Logradouro = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 72, nullable: false),
            Numero = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 6, nullable: false),
            Bairro = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 72, nullable: false),
            Complemento = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 72, nullable: false),
            Cidade = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 72, nullable: false),
            Estado = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 2, nullable: false),
            Pais = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 2, nullable: false),
            Cep = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 8, nullable: false),
            CodigoIbge = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 7, nullable: false),
            Identificador = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
            FornecedorId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_FornecedorEndereco", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_FornecedorEndereco_Fornecedor_FornecedorId",
                column: x => x.FornecedorId,
                principalTable: "Fornecedor",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "FornecedorTelefone",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            IdSistemaAntigo = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 32, nullable: false),
            Status = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            DataCadastro = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            UltimaMovimentacao = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            Ddi = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
            Ddd = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
            Telefone = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 9, nullable: false),
            Ramal = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
            TipoTelefone = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", maxLength: 1, nullable: false),
            Identificador = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
            FornecedorId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_FornecedorTelefone", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_FornecedorTelefone_Fornecedor_FornecedorId",
                column: x => x.FornecedorId,
                principalTable: "Fornecedor",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_FornecedorEmail_FornecedorId",
        table: "FornecedorEmail",
        column: "FornecedorId");

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_FornecedorEndereco_FornecedorId",
        table: "FornecedorEndereco",
        column: "FornecedorId");

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_FornecedorTelefone_FornecedorId",
        table: "FornecedorTelefone",
        column: "FornecedorId");
}
```

[Migration field size incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR6Ke.png)

This is my migration class

```
        public override void ConfigurarEntidade(EntityTypeBuilder<Fornecedor> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Fornecedor");

        #region Configurações da Entidade

        builder.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.TipoPessoa)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(1)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.Nome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(Fornecedor.TamanhoNome);

        builder.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.Apelido)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(Fornecedor.TamanhoNome);

        builder.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.Sexo)
            .IsRequired(false);

        builder.OwnsOne(fornecedor => fornecedor.Cnpj, cnpj =>
        {
            cnpj.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.NumeroCnpj)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasColumnName("Cnpj")
                .HasMaxLength(Cnpj.TamanhoCnpj)
                .IsRequired();

        });

        builder.OwnsOne(fornecedor => fornecedor.InscricaoEstadual, ie =>
        {
            ie.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.NumeroInscricao)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasColumnName("InscricaoEstadual")
                .HasMaxLength(InscricaoEstadual.TamanhoInscricaoEstadual)
                .IsRequired();

            ie.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.EstadoEmissor)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasColumnName("EstadoEmissorInscricaoEstadual")
                .HasMaxLength(InscricaoEstadual.TamanhoEstadoEmissor)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        builder.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.InscricaoMunicipal)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasColumnName("InscricaoMunicipal")
            .HasMaxLength(Fornecedor.TamanhoInscricaoMunicipal)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.OwnsOne(fornecedor => fornecedor.Cpf, cpf =>
        {
            cpf.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.NumeroCpf)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasColumnName("Cpf")
                .HasMaxLength(Cpf.TamanhoMaximoCpf)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        builder.OwnsOne(fornecedor => fornecedor.Rg, rg =>
        {
            rg.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.NumeroRg)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasColumnName("Rg")
                .HasMaxLength(Rg.TamanhoRg)
                .IsRequired();

            rg.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.EstadoEmissor)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasColumnName("EstadoEmissorRg")
                .HasMaxLength(Rg.TamanhoEstadoEmissor)
                .IsRequired();
        });


        builder.Ignore(fornecedor => fornecedor.DataNascimento);

        builder.Ignore(fornecedor => fornecedor.Imagem);

        #endregion

        #region Relacionamentos

        builder
            .HasMany(fornecedor => fornecedor.Emails)
            .WithOne(email => email.Fornecedor)
            .HasForeignKey(email => email.FornecedorId);

        builder
            .HasMany(fornecedor => fornecedor.Enderecos)
            .WithOne(endereco => endereco.Fornecedor)
            .HasForeignKey(endereco => endereco.FornecedorId);

        builder
            .HasMany(fornecedor => fornecedor.Telefones)
            .WithOne(telefone => telefone.Fornecedor)
            .HasForeignKey(telefone => telefone.FornecedorId);

        #endregion
    }
```

And this is my Entity

```
    public class Fornecedor : Entity
{
    public static readonly int TamanhoNome = 100;
    public static readonly int TamanhoApelido = 20;
    public static readonly int TamanhoInscricaoMunicipal = 20;
    public static readonly int TamanhoRg = 20;

    private string _nome;
    private string _nomeFantasia;

    public TipoPessoa TipoPessoa { get; private set; }

    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _nome; }
        private set { _nome = (value == null ? "" : value.RemoverEspacosDuplos().ToCapitalize().Trim()); }
    }

    public string Apelido
    {
        get { return _nomeFantasia; }
        private set { _nomeFantasia = (value == null ? "" : value.RemoverEspacosDuplos().ToCapitalize().Trim()); }
    }

    public Sexo? Sexo { get; private set; }

    public Cnpj Cnpj { get; private set; }

    public InscricaoEstadual InscricaoEstadual { get; private set; }

    public string InscricaoMunicipal { get; private set; }

    public Cpf Cpf { get; private set; }

    public Rg Rg { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; private set; }

    public string Imagem { get; private set; }

    public Fornecedor() { }
}
```

Comment: Where `type: "varchar"` is coming from? I mean, have you added it manually or it is generated by the add migration command? Can you post the entity and the fluent configuration?

Comment: The varchar type was added in migration class.

Comment: Ok, I see from the update they originate from `.HasColumnType("varchar")` fluent configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `type: "varchar"` argument to all these `table.Column<string>` calls. When this parameter is supplied, `maxLength` and some other parameters are ignored by the migration SQL generator. Because the `type` is supposed to be the actual database type, including the size and other constraints, for instance `varchar(100)` etc. When it's just `varchar`, SqlServer DDL treats it as `varchar(1)`.

With that being said, the question is what is causing the inclusion of that parameter. By convention it is not included (but the mapped database type is `nvarchar(maxLength)`), so it has to be specified in the model mappings.

It could have been done in two ways.

First is by applying `[Column(TypeName ="varchar")]` data annotation. However, if you do so, you'll get an exception when trying to generate a migration similar to this

> Data type 'varchar' is not supported in this form. Either specify the length explicitly in the type name, for example as 'varchar(16)', or remove the data type and use APIs such as HasMaxLength to allow EF choose the data type.

So it shouldn't be this way, but the second way of using `.HasColumnType("varchar")` fluent API. When you do so, surprisingly the migration is generated without any errors and contains the aforementioned parameter. I find this behavior at least inconsistent - both should throw or both should succeed.

Anyway, the solution is to put the max length inside the type name, e.g.

```
.HasColumnType("varchar(100)")
```

or better avoid `.HasColumnType` where possible. For instance, whether the `string` is mapped to `varchar` or `nvarchar` depends on `isUnicode` attribute which is `true` by default. Hence to get the desired `varchar(maxLength)` database type, replace all

```
.HasColumnType("varchar")
```

in your `OnModelCreating` with

```
.IsUnicode(false)
```

and let the existing `.HasMaxLenght` calls handle the max length. And don't forget to regenerate the migration.

Comment: Hello Ivan Stoev,

Thanks for your help.

I'm convinced that there is a bug in the Entity Framework Core. When I run migration with the command below, the database creation script is generated with the type and size information.

Comment: The `IsUnicode(false)` **does** work. Note that you must **remove** `.HasColumnType("varchar")` calls (or **replace** them with `.IsUnicode(false)` as mentioned in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

About `code`.IsUnicode(false)`code` in my `code`OnModelCreating`code` did not work.

```
builder.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.Nome)
.IsRequired()
.HasColumnType("varchar")
.IsUnicode(false)
.HasMaxLength(Fornecedor.TamanhoNome);
```

I was able to solve the problem this way

```
builder.Property(fornecedor => fornecedor.Nome)
.IsRequired()
.HasColumnType($"varchar({Fornecedor.TamanhoNome})");
//.IsUnicode(false)
//.HasMaxLength(Fornecedor.TamanhoNome);
```

Which results in

```
IdSistemaAntigo = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(32)", nullable: false),
```